# Retrieve the number of capture groups in any arbitrary Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know the number of capture groups a regex produces. Is there any better way than the following?

```
function getRegExpCaptureGroupsNum(r) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(new RegExp(r.source + '|').exec(''), 0).length - 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the `Array.slice` method here. This would be sufficient:

```
function getRegExpCaptureGroupsNum(r) {
    return RegExp(r.source + '|').exec('').length - 1;
}
```

Comment: Oops you're right ^^. It's been over a week and nobody came up with something better, so I'll be accepting this answer as best.